# How to do async validation on redux-form FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm struggling with how to do [async blur validation](https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/examples/asyncvalidation/) on a [FieldArray](https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/examples/fieldarrays/).

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/564ww30zx) of the issue I am having. Every time there is an `STOP_ASYNC_VALIDATION` it seems to clear the form's `asyncErrors` state. I'd like for the form to remember the errors for each item in the field array but I can't seem to figure that out.

If you enter the text "bad" for a hobby it will display the error text, but whenever you add a hobby or move between "bad" hobbies it will clear the errors. How do I preserve these errors and properly display each of them next to their respective field?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if this is the best approach, but I found to use redux-form [action creators](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/actioncreators.md/) to just track my own errors/warnings.